# How to re-enable admob in my app

Tags: android, admob

I got an email with contents:

[image]

HOW CAN I RE-ENABLE ADS ON MY APP???

My application has 1000+ downloads, I can't delete it and upload new app with other id to get ads.

Please help me, I am puzzled!

Comment: did you re-enabled your app? how?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue is serving ads in a way that AdMob is not okay with.  Check to make sure your app is not doing any of these:

- You cannot place the ads close enough to buttons that users may mistakenly click on the ad
- You cannot share/send user data or identities without their consent
- The app itself cannot violate the content guidelines - no advertising with AdMob if you are publishing a porn app.  This is most likely not the problem since Google's Play Store policies are essentially the same.
- You can't give the user extra incentive to click the add.  No saying "Click the add to make it disappear"
- You can't click your own ads

See this link for more details: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2753860?hl=en

Comment: I uploaded the application for 10 days ago. And I got email when i upload other app with same admod_id.
I want to re-enable, Is it possible?

Comment: You may be able to fill out a form to request that it be re-enabled, but that will depend on the reason for them disabling it.  What that the violation explanation?